# Capture std::array in lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I was trying to test some  simple C-style sort functions. In the driver program, I wrote something like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::array<int, 8> A = { 1, 0, 4, 5, 7, 2, 9, 3 };
    auto lambda = [&A](const std::function<void(int *A, int n)> &sorting_alg) {
        int n = A.size();
        sorting_alg(A.data(), n);
        std::cout << "=> ";
        print(A.data(), n);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    };

    auto do_bubble_sort = std::bind(lambda, bubble_sort);
    auto do_selection_sort  = std::bind(lambda, selection_sort);
    auto do_insertion_sort  = std::bind(lambda, insertion_sort);

    std::cout << "Bubble Sort :" << std::endl;
    do_bubble_sort();
    std::cout << "Selection Sort :" << std::endl;
    do_selection_sort();
    std::cout << "Insertion Sort :" << std::endl;
    do_insertion_sort();

    return 0;
}
```

I had the bind code, to which I could pass `A` to copy, but it confines my lambda to `size=8`, which I want to avoid. Is it possible to achieve this without using something like `std::vector`, etc?
As soon I change capture method of `A` to value-capture, it doesn't compile anymore. I wanted to use copies for the array, to test all sorting functions. Why can't I capture `std::array` by value? Why then size-inference works for reference case?

Comment: OT: Why not simply `std::function<void(int*, int)>`? What is the purpose of `A` and `n` in `std::function<void(int *A, int n)>`?

Comment: You're right! I just copied over the signature out of laziness.:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `operator()` of a lambda is `const` by default.  That means you can't modify any members of the lambda (it's captures).  When you capture by reference, this means you can't change the reference to refer to something else, but since you can't do that already it basically means nothing.  When you capture by value it makes that value `const`, which means you can no longer modify like your sorting method requires (you need `data` to return a non-const pointer).

To get around this you can use the `mutable` keyword to make the lambda's `operator()` not `const`.  That would look like

```
auto lambda = [A](const std::function<void(int *A, int n)> &sorting_alg) mutable {
    int n = A.size();
    sorting_alg(A.data(), n);
    std::cout << "=> ";
    print(A.data(), n);
    std::cout << std::endl;
};
```

Comment: (Re-)copy `A` in lambda seems more appropriated (so other sorting codes would sort original array, and not a sorted array.)

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't get your comment.  Capturing by value makes a copy.

Comment: I meant removing `mutable` and doing code like Guillaume Racicot's answer. sorting a copy of the `A` (of the lambda).

Comment: @DanielLangr: But you probably want to compare from same input, and not from sorted array. (and copy of input would be identical and actually have less complexity than sorting).

Comment: Also, I could write some timing function in the lambda.

Comment: @Jarod42 You're right, my bad. Didn't notice there is only a single lambda in OP's code.

Comment: @DanielLangr: I didn't notice the `std::bind`s which copy `lambda` on my side...

Comment: @NathanOliver: By reference parameters, I wanted to access the temporaries created by std::bind by reference. It might have been smarter to use r-value reference?

Answer (score 3):

You can capture by value, but you have to change the lambda to a mutable one.

When you capture by value, the captures are const by default. You can mark it mutable or make a copy locally:

```
auto lambda = [A](const std::function<void(int *A, int n)> &sorting_alg) {
    auto ALocal = A;
    int n = ALocal.size();
    sorting_alg(ALocal.data(), n);
    std::cout << "=> ";
    print(ALocal.data(), n);
    std::cout << std::endl;
};
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/dDDU6P)

This has the advantage of making the lambda callable multiple times.

You can do this with capture by reference too.

You can alternatively make the lambda mutable, but callable only once:

```
auto lambda = [A](const std::function<void(int *A, int n)> &sorting_alg) mutable {
    int n = A.size();
    sorting_alg(A.data(), n);
    std::cout << "=> ";
    print(A.data(), n);
    std::cout << std::endl;
};
```

Comment: *"but callable only once"* It is callable multiple times, those extra time would just sort a "sorted" array.

Comment: Are you referring to non-recursive call or in main() itself? Of course, bind made copies, but I still could get it to run more than once?

Comment: @user2338150 if you run such mutable lambda more than once, the data will already be sorted, making the initial problem to reappear.

Comment: I got it, if I called do_bubble_sort() twice, second iteration would run on sorted array itself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `operator()` of the lambda function is `const`-qualified by default. This means that the values captured by value are `const`-qualified in the lambda body. In your code, you are trying to invoke `std::function` with a non-`const` pointer to `int` initialized from the captured array, which is `const`.

To fix this you need to mark your lambda as `mutable` so that the generated `operator()` is no longer `const`-qualified:

```
auto lambda = [A](const std::function<void(int *A, int n)> &sorting_alg) mutable {
    ...
}
```